# NULL判定が意図した通り行われない

Tags: c++, visual-studio

デバッグでsampleDataの値を確認すると、`0x00000000<NULL>`となっていましたが、下記のif文の中に入りません。またNULL != sampleDataにしてもif文の中の処理にいきません。

```
HRESULT SampleClass::SampleEvent(SAMPLE_DATA** sampleData)

if (NULL == sampleData)
{

}
```

かなり初歩的なことかもしれませんが、もしかして、`0x00000000<NULL>`の表記は、値がNULLであることを指していないのでしょうか？
それとも、表現の仕方があっているかわかりませんが、sampleDataがNULLに対応していないということでしょうか？

ご教授をお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

質問内容にやや曖昧な部分があって、明確な回答を得られない可能性があります。
以下の点に注意して、もう一度やってみてはどうでしょう。

(1)当該のコードを含むプロジェクトまたはソリューションを、
　　「デバッグの構成」を選択して「ビルド」した(または「フルビルド」した)。
　　かつ、それは成功した。

(2)「デバッグの構成」を選択して、または(1)のまま「デバッグ開始した」。
　　(注意:VSは「リリースの構成」でも「デバッグ開始」できてしまいます。
　　　　この場合、「ウォッチ」の結果は実際の値を表示できません)

(3)当該の関数内にブレークポイントがあり、そこでブレークした。

(4)引数「sampleData」を「ウォッチペイン」にコピーして値を確認した。
　　かつ、sampleDataは0x00000000であった。

(5)かつ、「同名のグローバル変数」「同名のクラスメンバ変数」などは
　　存在しないことが確認されている。

(6)「ステップ実行した」が、if( NULL==sampleData)の「真」の判定に入らない。

(7)NULL判定したいのはsampleData(=ポインタのポインタ)であって、
　　「*sampleData」(=ポインタ)ではない。
　　すなわち、コードは正しい。

Comment: (7)sampleDataではなく、*sampleDataがNULLだった気がします。

Answer (score 0):

sampleClassとSAMPLE_DATAを書いた方が、回答しやすいと思います。
ちなみに下記のソースでは問題ありませんでした。

```
struct SAMPLE_DATA {
    int a;
    int b;
};
class SampleClass {
public:
    void SampleEvent(SAMPLE_DATA** sampleData);

};
void SampleClass::SampleEvent(SAMPLE_DATA** sampleData)
{
    if (NULL == sampleData)
    {
        int aaa = 123;
    }

}
int main()
{
    SampleClass *s = new SampleClass();
    s->SampleEvent(NULL);
}
```